# How do I handle the math of hex maps?

Tags: battle-map, map-making

I'm having trouble calculating distances on hex-mapped worlds. The math, even at the regional scale, is difficult.

But I'm also interested in distances at the world-scale. I'm targeting icosahedral maps of planets / worlds in particular.
I'm looking for distance calculations "as the crow flies" regardless of obstacles, as opposed to the length of the most direct valid path.

How do such programs as "Traveller Heaven & Earth" calculate the various distances between hexes, particularly at the planet-scale (with those odd pentagons getting into the path)?
Perhaps there is some material on this topic in classical tabletop/boardgame stuff, but I never played such games and thus have no access to such material yet.

Any hints on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Amit Patel has a nice blog that has a [section regarding hex maps](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/gameprog.html#hex). I especially like the [Isometric cube coordinate](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/Articles/Hexagon2.html) system.

Regarding icosahedrons, consider each facet to be a triangular hex map where edge hexes(`FJM`, `NLI` and `BCD`) are shared between two facets and corner hexes (`A`, `E` and `O`) are actually pentagons common to all five facets at the vertex.

```
    O
   M N
  J K L
 F G H I
A B C D E
```

The regular approaches to hexagonal distance calculations work well with this kind of map. At the vertex pentagons, continuing towards any two hex(pent?) edges opposing the edge entered is equivalent.

---

Here is a [Goldberg polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron), which is the the [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron) of a [geodesic sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_sphere):

[image: dual of geodesic sphere]

---

Also, please take a look at this [icosahedral world map generator](http://inkwellideas.com/2011/11/icosahedral-world-map-generator-updated-resize-hexes-loadsave-export-an-image/). Hope it helps

Comment: Ah, that's great! Exactly what I want, really like the programming part.

Answer (score 4):

It is all to do with [graph theory](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphTheory.html).  You can model your hexes as nodes in a graph. The arcs will just be of fixed length with a cost of travel depending on either hex "geography".  From there on, a [shortest path algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShortestPathProblem.html) will give you want you want.  The generic case is NP hard -- aka travelling salesman -- but there are some good approximations.

As "crow fly" would mean that you have a fixed cost for each arc.  This may give you more than one optimal path as they will have the same cost of travel.  As an example:

```
 A
B C
 D
```

The cost of the path ABD is the same as the cost of the path ACD.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about large hexagonal maps on spheres, there is no clean way to do this, since you cannot perfectly cover a sphere in equally-sized hexagons. (Think about the irregular patterns on a soccer ball or golf ball.) The other methods mentioned here are good for grids and graphs, but if you're trying to simply calculate distances on a sphere you need to revert to [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance). If you're attempting to cover the entire Earth in 5' hex squares, for example, convert each one to a latitude and longitude and use this method. (This might not be the scope of your problem at all, though.)

Note that Heaven & Earth approximates planets as an [icosahedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) projection (giant d20) of a hexagonal map, as seen [here](http://www.downport.com/wbd/H&E_07.htm), and the other methods mentioned would work well in this case.

---

Additionally, there is an excellent (if slightly programmer-centric) article on the subject of hex grids [here](http://3dmdesign.com/development/hexmap-coordinates-the-easy-way).

Answer (score 2):

### Hexes are simple

First of all, let's look at a hex and see how it measures itself. In general each hexagon can be described by its "inscribing circle" and its "circumscribing circle". Those two measurements also are the distance of flat to flat and tip to tip respectively. With the inner circle set to "1 unit diameter", the circumscribing circle is roughly 1.155 of diameter, of 15.5% more, and the length of a flat is half the circumscribing circle's diameter or 0.577 of the unit.

[image]

Due to the Magic of hexagons, going from one hex to its neighbor is *always* the distance between the flats. Going from one hex into one direction and then one further is a distance of 2 and so on. So far, so good, right? The approximation assumes pretty much that to get from one hex to another, you always have to get to the *center* of the neighboring zone. So you just count the number of hexes (or filling pentagons) and multiply by the scale of the hex, as you can see below

[image: Distances to non neighboring Hexes]

### Hexes are complicated

Do note that the distance *as the crow flies* will be shorter if your path is making a turn or passes in between two hexes. The closest non-neighbor of any hex is 1.73 hexes away - which is \$\sqrt{3}\$. Why? Well... Trigonometry demands it. You go to the neighboring hex, do a 120° turn and then go to the next hex. You effectively moved the distance of one and a half of the circumscribing circle's diameters or three radii \$D=\frac 3 2 D_c=3 R_c\$. The 120° turn means we can describe that distance as \$2 \times \sin({60})= 2 \times \frac S 1=3 R_c=\frac 3 2 D_c\$. A little bit of math magic turns that into the actual diameter of the circumscribing circle \$\frac 4 3 \times sin({60})=D_c\ = \frac {2 \sqrt{3}} 3\$ This in turn makes solving D trivial: \$D=\frac 3 2 D_c=\frac 3 2 \times \frac {2 \sqrt{3}} 3 = \sqrt{3}\$

[image]

#### Spherical bodies?!

Using Trigonometry, the principle to calculate the distance *as the crow flies* can be applied even for larger flat maps, using the *unfolded* pattern of the body onto the flat plane. While unfolding ignores the curvature of a planetoid, it gives a reasonable estimation of a sphere, that cuts the body. However, not all flat areas can create bodies: hexagons can create only macro-spheres if you include a least some pentagons of the same edge length, such as with Fullerenes.

[image: Fullerene Spheres]

Depending on the pattern chosen - such as a [truncated Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron), the pattern and its unfolding will look neater than others, but usually, there will be gaps over which one will need to "teleport" when unraveling such surfaces, usually around the pentagons. Calculating *as the crow flies* distances on such bodies can be very complicated, but provided you have the unwrapping of such a body can be done almost trivially with a ruler - provided that you account for the angle shift over the gaps. For simplicity, the path chosen in the image below only intersects edges with right angles or follows edges. While you need to measure it in pieces, just using a ruler is most simple here.

[image]